# in node.js, how to pass variables to :stylus filter from jade?

Tags: node.js, pug, stylus

creating a variable within `jade` that I wish the `stylus` filter to use.

using `#{var}` does not appear to work.  for example, this code:

```
  - var color1 = 'blue'
  stylus:
    div
      background-color pink
      color #{color1}
```

gives resulting error:

```
/home/data/tnt/server/node/www/tech/cool.jade:2
   1| div
   2|   background-color pink
 > 3|   color #{color1}
   4|   

expected "indent", got "outdent"
```

how do I get the `jade` variable `color1` visible within the `stylus` filter?

Comment: What do you mean on "the following breaks:"? Do you get an error or the redered output is not correct?

Comment: @nemesv - thanks - added the error message to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filters (like stylus, markdown etc.) are executed  during "compile-time", and only once.

But text replacement is done during run-time, so **filters don't have access to variables.**

Filters can only access the raw text eg. `color #{color1}` and not `color blue`

As a workaround you can create a helper method where you do stylus templating and rendering yourself as suggested in multiple places (I've only found examples which are used the markdown filter but filters are working the same so they apply also the `stylus` filter):

- [Jade: Pass markdown filter a variable.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/express-js/8H4HNcoeekk)
- [:markdown filter processing the text of a String variable](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/404)
- [:markdown with variable](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/895)

Comment: this makes sense in a way, but it doesn't make it fun.  it would be far easier for me, as a programmer, if I could say `::stylus`, meaning "interpret this runtime", rather than having to build that helper method edifice.

Comment: forgot to say thanks - thanks!  in this case I think I'll have `jade` write the `style` section instead of deferring to `stylus` - a lot less complicated