# Filter nesting failed in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have some filters:

```
var jade = require('jade');
jade.filters.Posts = function(block) {
    return '{block:Posts}'+jade.render(block)+'{/block:Posts}';
};
jade.filters.Audio = function(block) {
    return '{block:Audio}'+jade.render(block)+'{/block:Audio}';
};
jade.filters.Video = function(block) {
    return '{block:Video}'+jade.render(block)+'{/block:Video}';
};
```

And have some input

```
:Posts
    Posts
        :Audio
            | Audio
        :Video
            | Video
```

So I have an error:

```
 >> unknown filter ":Audio"
```

Can I handle or fix this problem?

**PS** You can look at the code in this [repository](https://github.com/matmuchrapna/Hampi/) — I'm using grunt and grunt-contrib-jade plugin, but to force grunt-contrib-jade work with filters you should edit ./node_modules/grunt-contrib-jade/tasks/jade.js to reflect [changes](https://github.com/matmuchrapna/grunt-contrib-jade/blob/issues/50/tasks/jade.js) from this [pull request](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade/pull/54).

**PS2**: I found the *stumbling block*. When I use `render()` method inside filter, I invoke it from local jade instance, which is don't know anything about filters, but global jade instance (from Gruntfile.js) have all information about that filters. That's why the main question is: **how can I throw global Jade-instance to file with filters?**

**PS3**: I don't know how create fiddle for such case. But you can clone my [Hampi repo](https://github.com/matmuchrapna/Hampi/), implement [changes to grunt-contrib-jade from my PR to them](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade/pull/54), then at start run `npm i`. To compile templates run `grunt jade`. Pay attention to [these line](https://github.com/matmuchrapna/Hampi/blob/master/src/templates/body.jade#L15-L20) in body.jade and [commented section](https://github.com/matmuchrapna/Hampi/blob/master/src/templates/filters/filters.js#L21-L36) in filters.

**PS4. I find the reason and it in different scope. I describe it with details [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jade/pull/54#issuecomment-24801775). Can you solve this issue?**

---

*I'm open to additional answers and I will accept fixes in jade core (if it would be required).*

Comment: You might try to open a github issue to get support. Filters are still marked as unstable, so you might influence design decisions (if it's a bug) or make them update the docs (if it's already possible).

Comment: How are you testing this ? I did the same and it works for me. Can you post the rest of code.

Comment: @bergie I'm already create issues but I have no response to them

Comment: @user568109 I updated the question with PS-section

Comment: @user568109 please see my code and also can you show yours one?

Comment: @user568109 I found stumbling block. **PPS**-section added to question

Comment: @user568109 added **PS3**-section

Comment: The steps you take to allow filter to be used with jade plugin should work. So I guess it is having some problems. Also did you overwrite everything inside tasks/jade.js with the code mentioned in the issue. You should not use separate jade other than the one being used inside that file. Can you post the changes made inside that file. If file is big post the relevant part or give a link.

Comment: @user568109 Added PS4 to question with details I found about reason my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just should bind global jade instance to filters like this:

```
var jade = require('jade');
if (options.filters) {
  // have custom filters
  Object.keys(options.filters).forEach(function(filter) {
    if (_.isFunction(data)) {
      // have custom options
      jade.filters[filter] = options.filters[filter].bind({jade: jade, locals: data()});
    } else {
      // have no custom options
      jade.filters[filter] = options.filters[filter].bind({jade: jade });
    }

  });
}
```

See implementation here — in this [**commit**](https://github.com/matmuchrapna/grunt-contrib-jade/commit/291f04d86e9e7a5eb80ca602e943dfe02c40d210)

Comment: Great :) I could have never thought in that way :) thank you for answer

Comment: The solution is great. Too bad I don't know much grunt and could not help with the grunt tasks. I could never have come up with this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right at problem place, the problem is in the `filter.js` file

location `jade/lib/filters.js`

```
var transformers = require('transformers');

module.exports = filter;
function filter(name, str, options) {
  if (typeof filter[name] === 'function') {
    var res = filter[name](str, options);
  } else if (transformers[name]) {
    var res = transformers[name].renderSync(str, options);
    if (transformers[name].outputFormat === 'js') {
      res = '<script type="text/javascript">\n' + res + '</script>';
    } else if (transformers[name].outputFormat === 'css') {
      res = '<style type="text/css">' + res + '</style>';
    } else if (transformers[name].outputFormat === 'xml') {
      res = res.replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('unknown filter ":' + name + '"');
  }
  return res; // returns RES that is not defined in scope of function.
}
filter.exists = function (name, str, options) {
  return typeof filter[name] === 'function' || transformers[name];
};
```

Here I have identified one flaw that you can correct like this,

```
var transformers = require('transformers');

module.exports = filter;
function filter(name, str, options) {
  var res;//defined a variable which is global to the scope of function.
  if (typeof filter[name] === 'function') {
    res = filter[name](str, options);
  } else if (transformers[name]) {
    res = transformers[name].renderSync(str, options);
    if (transformers[name].outputFormat === 'js') {
      res = '<script type="text/javascript">\n' + res + '</script>';
    } else if (transformers[name].outputFormat === 'css') {
      res = '<style type="text/css">' + res + '</style>';
    } else if (transformers[name].outputFormat === 'xml') {
      res = res.replace(/'/g, '&#39;');
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error('unknown filter ":' + name + '"');
  }
  return res;
}
filter.exists = function (name, str, options) {
  return typeof filter[name] === 'function' || transformers[name];
};
```

It may be possible that nesting under some function makes audio function out of scope. Does audio function works alone!?

although there may be other things if the problem not solved, please create a fiddle for your for better understanding.

Comment: Your changes didn't help in this situation.

Comment: > Does audio function works alone!? – Yes. Also it works nestedly if all filters dont't return `jade.render(block)`

Comment: I added guide how to test my code in *PS3* section of question.

Comment: Can you change line no 25 here https://github.com/matmuchrapna/Hampi/blob/master/src/templates/body.jade#L15-L20 from :Audio to Audio and test it.!

Comment: Excellent Library you are developing there :)

Comment: If I change :Audio to Audio I will get tag, not filter. It's not what I want to achieve.

Comment: Added PS4 to question with details I found about reason my problem